# Change Woocommerce Category list to inline

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have found come code which works for me, but I want the sub categories to display horizontally (instead of listed top to bottom), and without the bullets on the right hand side. Also I need them to look like buttons (eg. background color with padding).

Any suggestions?

current code:

```
$categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' ); 

 //For checking category exit or not

 if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $category ) ) : 


   foreach($categories as $category) :
      // get the children (if any) of the current cat
      $children = get_categories( array ('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'parent' => $category->term_id ));

    if ( count($children) == 0 ) {
       // if no children, then echo the category name.
        echo $category->name;
    }
  endforeach;

 endif;
```

Comment: That is just a matter of applying css, you could possibly add some html to the output of your code. Do you have a URL to the relevant website?

Comment: Thanks I just assumed the layout would need to be included in the above snippet, but have achieved this with some css